# Storing data temporarily in nodejs application

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, nestjs, temporary-files

I'm developing a nodejs back-end application which will fetch data from third-party Hotel API provider based on the user input from the Angular application. User should be able to filter and sort the received data like filtering price, hotel rating and sorting price, hotel name etc. but unfortunately API doesn't support this. So I thought to store that data in nodejs temporarily but I'm not sure what's the right approach. Will Redis support this?. A good suggestion will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Redis should be able to support something like this. That or you could do all of the sorting client side and save all the hotel information in local or session storage. Either route you go with you'll need to make sure to save the entire response with a unique key so that it is easy to fetch, or if you save individual values to Redis make sure each has a key to query against. Also keep in mind Redis is best for caching information for short term periods rather than long term solutions like PostgreSQL and MySQL. But for just temp responses, it should be a fine approach.